# Vidual Studio 2017 C# System.Data.OleDb cannot read newer Excel files

Tags: c#, excel, oledb, oledbconnection

I use Visual Studio Professional 2017 (15.9.16 and .NET Framework 4.7.02558), coding in C#.

I have existing code using System.Data.OleDB that successfully reads older Excel files, but newer ones fail to be read, getting the error "external table is not in the expected format". Full exception is shown at the end of this post.

I claim this is a version problem because if I down-convert the file to, say, Excel 2003, then reading the workbook succeeds. The only difference being the version of the Excel file.

I've done some initial poking around hoping to find that I merely need upgrade some component in Visual Studio, but I have not had luck in this respect; there are so many pieces to this puzzle I don't know where to begin.

```
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException
HResult=0x80004005
Message=External table is not in the expected format.
Source=System.Data
StackTrace:
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionInternal..ctor(OleDbConnectionString constr, OleDbConnection connection)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreateNonPooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPoolGroup poolGroup, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection.Open()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what newer version format you're saving in, since you've already isolated it to this specific issue?

Comment: Aren't versions after 2003 when Excel changed the format from .xls (binary) to .xlsx (XML)? Could it just be that the version you're using is outdated or that it's trying to read an XML-based file but expecting the binary (you didn't post code or anything so I genuinely don't know)?

Comment: I'm not saving into a newer format at all. I'm receiving Excel files from an external party. I have no control over the version I receive. I then downgrade the file manually by importing it into Excel and doing a Save As. The original is .xlsx compressed. I found can use 7zip to uncompress the xlsx, resulting in several xml files. But ... how can I read this data? It isn't just a matter of reading some XML, it would need to know who the various extracted xml files relate to one another.

Comment: fwiw my connection string is "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 XML;Data Source=C:\\whatever.xlsx;"

Answer (score 0):

OK I have come across the proper solution. Instead of OleDb, I should be using OpenXML (DocumentFormat.OpenXML). I am getting myself up-to-speed on this approach now